# Como recuperar a primeira letra de um array Swift

Tags: string, swift

Gostaria de saber como faço para recuperar a primeira letra de um elemento de um array

```
var wordEasy = ["uva", "manga"]

var teste: String = wordEasy[0]
```

Gostaria de recuperar apenas a letra u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode extender o Array type usando o `where` clause para extender apenas elementos que podem ser convertidos em String. Crie uma propriedade para retornar um array de Strings. Use map para converter cada elemento em String, extraia o primeiro elemento do array de caracteres usando a propriedade prefix(n) dos characters e converta o Character para String antes de retorná-lo.

```
extension Array where Element: StringLiteralConvertible {
    var initials: [String] {
        return map{String(String($0).characters.prefix(1))}
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
let frutas = ["uva", "manga"]

let frutasInitials = frutas.initials   // ["u","m"]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado galera =D deu certo!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar essa extensão

```
extension String {

  subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
    return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
  }

  subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return String(self[i] as Character)
  }

  subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
    let end = start.advancedBy(r.endIndex - r.startIndex)
    return self[Range(start: start, end: end)]
  }
}
```

O resultado:

```
"abcde"[0] === "a"
"abcde"[0...2] === "abc"
"abcde"[2..<4] === "cd"
```

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language

Answer (score 2):

Se não quiser usar a extensão sugerida na [resposta do Jeferson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109746), use o mesmo método que ela:

```
var wordEasy = ["uva", "manga"]
var teste: String = wordEasy[0]
let u = teste[teste.startIndex]
print(u)
```

Vale ainda uma olhada na [referência oficial da Apple sobre strings em Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Comment: As duas resposta são otimas, pois fiquei com mais um problema, eu preciso atribuir cada letra em uma variavel diferente, creio que o starIndex nao da certo, existe alguma outra forma de eu fazer isso?

eu fiz dessa forma

<i>let word = wordEasy[0]
        
        for var i = 0; i < wordEasy.count
        
        print(word.stringByPaddingToLength(1, withString: "", startingAtIndex: 2))</i>

mas nao acho que ficou legal pois nao uso o withString

Comment: @BrunoBafilli Acho que isso já renderia uma pergunta separada!

Comment: verdade você está certo!

Muito obrigado amigo